# Is it possible to select the items on a form that are sent in onSubmit?

Tags: java, javascript, model-view-controller, jsp

Of the different data entered in a form, is it possible to select the particular items I want to send onSubmit? Here I need only File, date and comments to be submitted through submitProxy.php. But, I want the rest of the data to be passed to another database on another server. Here I have only one form though.

```
<div id="submit">
<table
style="font-family: 'Lucida Sans Unicode', 'Lucida Grande', sans-serif"
; border="0" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0" align="center">

<form id="frm" name="frm" action="http://app1/submitProxy.php"
    method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <tr>
        <th colspan="2" bgcolor="#004276"><font color="white">
                Submit a File 
        </th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>File:</td>
        <td><input name="upfile" type="file" value="">
        </td>
    </tr>
    <input type="hidden" name="email" readonly="readonly"
        value="<%=user.getUserName()%>" /> <input type="hidden"
        name="reanalyze" value="true" />
    <tr>
        <td>Case or Reference Number:</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="caseno" value="${caseno}" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Obtained via:</td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><dd>Search Warrant:</dd></td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" name="searchWarrant"
            onclick="showhidefield()" value="Y">
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Search Warrant Number:</td>
        <td><input name="searchWarrantNumber" type="text"
            value="${searchWarrantNumber}" /> <br />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Jurisdiction:</td>
        <td><input name="jurisdiction" type="text"
            value="${jurisdiction}" /> <br />
        </td>
    </tr>
    </div>
<tr>
    <td><dd>Grand Jury:</dd></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="grandJury" value="Y"
        onclick="checkGrandJury()">
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><dd>Found in the wild:</dd>
    </td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="foundInTheWild" value="Y"
        onclick="checkFoundInTheWild()">
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><dd>Email:</dd></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="obtainedEmail" value="Y"
        onclick="checkObtainedEmail()">
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><dd>Other:</dd></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="obtainedOther" value="Y"
        onclick="checkObtainedOther()">
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Environment:</td>
    <td><select name="sandboxes[]" size="1">
            <option value="00-0C-29-CF-B8-A6">VMSB1 - Windows 7</option>
            <option value="00-0C-29-0A-AB-9A">VMSB2 - Windows XP</option>
    </select>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Comments:</td>
    <td><textarea name="notes">Add comments here...</textarea><br>

    </td>
</tr>
<td colspan="2">
    <center>
        <input type="submit" name="button" value="Submit"
            onclick="onSubmit()" />
    </center>
</td>
</form>
</table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

*All* your form data gets sent to *one* server when you submit the form.

What you do with it - whether you want to ignore it, process it, or pass it on - is totally up to you.

Comment: The problem i am facing is that, i am submitting through an api which will take the file and add it to the database tables. And I dont have control over the database and I cannot change it. But I need the form to have certain fields like "where did you obtain it from". But this field is not supported by the api.php. So it will not take it and it will also ignore the fields (which appear later) which the api will actually take in because it had faced additional parameters earlier.

Comment: Sounds like you need to have a separate script which *can* handle all the form values, which then does your API call, processes the other values, and returns an appropriate result back to the client

Answer (score 0):

You can set the `disabled` attribute on elements you don't want submitted.